# How to Run a spark job in cluster mode in GCP?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

In GCP, we want to run a spark job in cluster mode on a data[proc cluster. Currently we are using the following command:-

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster xxxx-xxxx-dataproc-cluster01 --region us-west2 --xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx --jars gs://xxx-xxxx-poc/cluster-compute/lib/xxxxxxxx-cluster-computation-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-allinone.jar --properties=spark:spark.submit.deployMode=cluster --properties=spark.driver.extraClassPath=/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/ -- -c xxxxxxxx -a
```

However using above the job is being submitted in local mode. We need to run in cluster mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it in cluster mode by specifying the following `--properties spark.submit.deployMode=cluster`

In your example the deployMode doesn't look correct.

```
--properties=spark:spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
```

Looks like `spark:` is extra.

Here is the entire command for the job submission

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster XXXXX --region us-central1 --properties="spark.submit.deployMode=cluster" gs://dataproc-examples/pyspark/hello-world/hello-world.py
```

Below is the screenshot of the job running in cluster mode

[image: Spark Job Configuration]

## Update

To pass multiple properties below is the dataproc job submit

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster cluster-e0a0 --region us-central1 --properties="spark.submit.deployMode=cluster","spark.driver.extraClassPath=/xxxxxx/configuration/cluster-mode/" gs://dataproc-examples/pyspark/hello-world/hello-world.py
```

On running the job below is the screenshot which shows the deployMode is Cluster and the extra class path is also set

[image: Multiple properties]

Comment: spark: is extra , But the job is not failing with that. Also same out put even after removng the same.  Also when we see the parameters in dataproc jobs we are not getting the spark.master. Please advice.

Comment: I have added the exact command with screenshot. You can see that the job is running in cluster mode. If the parameters don't meet the criteria the job will not fail but will fall back to the default which would be the client mode.

Comment: gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster xxxx-xxx-dataproc-cluster01 --region us-west2 --class com.xxxx.dataflow.xxxx.xxxx.main.xxxxxxxBuilderMain --jars gs://xxxxx-dataproc-poc/cluster-compute/lib/xxxxxxxx.jar --properties=spark.submit.deployMode=cluster,spark.driver.extraClassPath=/xxxxxx/configuration/cluster-mode/ -- -c xxxxxxxx -a
Job [xxxxxxxxx] submitted.
Waiting for job output...
20/03/16 12:12:34 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxxxx-anon-dataproc-cluster01-m/xxxxx.26:8032
20/03/16 12:12:34 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProx

Comment: 2020-03-16 12:16:16.367]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$reviveOffers$1.apply(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:88)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint$$anonfun$reviveOffers$1.apply(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:86)
 at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
 at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)

Comment: I have updated my answer to show the multiple properties how it needs to be set.

Answer (score 0):

If want to run the spark job through cloud shell use below command

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --cluster cluster-test
```

-- class org.apache.spark.examples.xxxx --jars file:///usr/lib/spark/exampleas/jars/spark-examples.jar --1000